# As3 Pause Btn not working

Tags: actionscript-3, visible, frame-rate

I have been working on a game with falling objects and I made a pause button for it. Every time I click the pause Button it is supposed to make a menu visible, but it does not display until you move your mouse or make some kind of interaction. Any Ideas.

```
pauseBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_Clic);
function fl_Clic(event: MouseEvent): void {
hide1()
nextObject.stop()
pausemenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_Clic1);
pausereplay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_Clic2);
pauseplay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_Clic3);
stage.frameRate = 0
}
```

hide1() toggles the visibility of the objects

```
function hide1() {
pauseback.visible = !pauseback.visible
pauseplay.visible = !pauseplay.visible
pausereplay.visible = !pausereplay.visible
pausemenu.visible = !pausemenu.visible
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the frameRate to 0 just stop your falling objects. Setting the frameRate to 0 is probably effecting all drawing.

Comment: Just to add to this, according to the AS3 docs, a value of 0 isn't really valid for stage.frameRate. It might be internally getting set to 0.01 instead, which, as mentioned will probably cause unknown issues.